# Why isn't Xcode crash report revealing the source code?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7

I've received my first crash report through TestFlight which I can see in the Organizer:

[image: Crash report in Xcode Organizer]

There are a couple of problems I'm having trying to debug the crash:

When I click the "Open in Project..." button, the project isn't automatically opened. Fine, but it's not even listed in the list of recent projects that's offered up to me as a next step (nothing is listed there, even though this is the only app I'm actively working on at the moment):

[image: Browse recent projects]

I click the "Browse..." button to open the .xcworkspace file for my project, but once the project opens, nothing useful happens. All I see is the Debug navigator opened with the crashed threads but nothing opens on the right side (editor):

[image: Debug navigator with crashed threads but nothing else!]

Expanding the threads and clicking on the individual stack frames doesn't do anything.

The source code of the .xcworkspace file is the same code that was used to create the build that crashed. The app was archived and submitted to TestFlight with debug symbols and bitcode enabled. It's developed in Swift 2.2 with a few CocoaPods.

I've reviewed Apple's documentation on this (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AnalyzingCrashReports/AnalyzingCrashReports.html) but I still can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

What can I do to get Xcode to show me the source code that corresponds to this crash report?

Comment: You didn't delete the archive after submitting it, right?

Comment: No, the archives are still there. However, I've had to start uploading my builds to TestFlight using Application Loader because Xcode has started giving me an error -22421 when attempting to upload through the Organizer interface since about 3 builds ago.